# bsod every time a handle to a driver is created

Tags: windows, kernel, drivers

im writing a driver and I have a problem

everytime I try to open a handle to my driver using CreateFile, I get bsod (Access Violation)

It's important to mention that my driver loads successfuly and I dont get any errors

does someone knows how to handle it ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll really need to post some code...

Answer (score 1):

!analyze -v is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on creating [Kernel Dump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc266502.aspx) in Windows settings and then analyze dump in [WinDbg](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ZwCreateFile or Createfile? You can't use CreateFile in a driver because that is a usermode function and drivers run in kernel mode. Instead call ZwCreateFile which is the kernel mode version of CreateFile.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible fault source: the driver-internal function for handling IRP_MJ_CREATE is either incorrectly assigned or faulty.

But you can only guess without analyzing the dump (maybe in conjunction with the symbols database of your driver [the PDB files]).